# Resharper warning casting enum to UIntPtr, but no compiler warning

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-7.1

In the code below, Resharper gives me a warning: `Cannot cast expression of type 'Color' to type 'UIntPtr'`. (Actually, Resharper thinks it's an actual error.)

However, there is no compiler warning and it works fine.

This looks like a Resharper bug to me. Is it? Or is there something bad about it that the compiler isn't worrying about? (I'm using Resharper 7.1.1)

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public enum Color { Red, Green, Blue }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIntPtr test = (UIntPtr) Color.Red; // Resharper warning, no compile warning.
        }
    }
}
```

I can make the warning go away by casting the value to an int first, so I have a workaround:

```
UIntPtr test = (UIntPtr)(int) Color.Red;
```

Comment: Best guess is that resharpers problems is that it may fail at runtime or behave unexpectedly between platforms

Comment: It might also cause problems on 64bit systems.

Comment: @alzaimar How? I cannot see why...

Comment: Yeah I don't think it can cause problems - the underlying enum has int values that can always be cast into a UIntPtr.

Comment: I thought pointers (UIntPtr) are 8 bytes on 64 bit systems. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This looks like a Resharper bug to me. Is it?

[Yes](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-78748) :

> **RSRP-78748 False 'conversion does not exist' (UIntPtr)**
>
> ```
> using System;
>
> class A
> {
>     static void Main()
>     {
>         E? x = 0;
>         UIntPtr z = (UIntPtr)x;
>     }
> }
> enum E { }
> ```
>
> It is a known spec devation.

Not fixed as of 2013-03-05.